# Facebook Open ID url?

Tags: openid

As I know Facebook has embraced Open ID but I can't find  the url of it.

**Eg.** For Google it is: https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id

Likewise, what is the open ID url for facebook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can log in to Facebook using OpenID, but Facebook (unlike Google) is not an OpenID provider. You cannot log in to other services with OpenID using your Facebook account.

Comment: Hmmm..so need to use Facebook C# SDK for this. This will increase my work more than anything else :(

Answer (score 1):

Right Now Facebook is not OpenID provider. It supports OAuth for authentication.
For more information you can see this link http://developers.facebook.com/

Answer (score 0):

https://register.facebook.com/editaccount.php?ref=mb&drop

Just go to the section called "linked accounts" and set it.
If you are already logged in to any of the open id providers you will automatically login to facebook.com